# Android Facebook SDK - Null GraphUser

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I am trying to implement the Facebook SDK in my Android application but so far I had no success.
I have followed all the steps in the following tutorial by Facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

Yet, nothing worked - the GraphUser always returns null.
I have added the debug hash into Facebook and I have done everything that I was told to do.

Your help will be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: follow this tutorial. it works for me https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/

Comment: Thank you, I will try it and let you know whether it worked or not.

Comment: I faced the same issue and insanely spend 5hours to figure out that I missed to add Internet permission:(

Comment: Thank you Manik, in the next project that I need to implement the Facebook SDK I will keep that in mind (I eventually quit that project since my idea was already done).

Answer (score 3):

Oh, that I also had same issue today, I solved it by simply adding the `Internet` permission to the project `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Wow thank you.  Failing with a null response here is really uninformative, I don't know why the Facebook SDK does that.